# How do I record 10 second videos in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo-camera

I have a page of an expo-camera view and a record button, The button activates the camera or disables it if its running, I want to record videos with a max length of 10 seconds, then start recording again after the video is saved, and keep doing this until the user presses the button again to disable the camera

the code is based on this tutorial
https://github.com/chelseafarley/ExpoVideoRecordingTutorials/blob/main/App.js

But I edited it to remove the confirmation page, The video is saved immediately after recording finishes